# Realm with RxJava2 Flowable incorrect thread

Tags: realm, rx-java2

I am   trying to understand how work with `Realm` and `RxJava2`together (for async transactions) and did some sample project with transactions:

```
 private void writeAllUsers() {
        Realm.getDefaultInstance().executeTransactionAsync(realm -> realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(users));
    }

    private void getAllUsers() {
        getUsers().observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe(this::successGetUser, this::handleUserError);
    }

    private Flowable<RealmResults<User>> getUsers() {
        return Realm.getDefaultInstance()
                .where(User.class)
                .findAllAsync()
                .asFlowable();
    }
```

But when I call `getAllUsers`, I get exception:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Realm access from incorrect thread.
>   Realm objects can only be accessed on the thread they were created.

What I did wrong in this case?

Comment: Every `getInstance()` call should have a matching `close()` call, but only when the Realm or any of its Results will no longer be accessed.

Answer (score 1):

`RealmResults<T>` represents a thread-local collection of proxy views, where due to Realm's MVCC architecture, they are bound to the current thread-local version of the database.

This means that a managed RealmResults or Realm or RealmObject **cannot be passed between threads**.

So you cannot and mustn't do this with a RealmResults :

```
getUsers()
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())

.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
```

Passing managed results from `io` to `main thread` is no-no!

---

`asFlowable` just wraps the RealmChangeListener (only valid on looper threads) as a Flowable, so thread confinement is still a thing.

In fact, it will never terminate, and you should make sure you unsubscribe.

So to hide the results as Flowable in such a way that it works on any thread, assuming you don't do thread jumps with it:

```
private Flowable<RealmResults<User>> getUsers(Realm realm) {
    if(realm.isAutoRefresh()) {
       return realm
            .where(User.class)
            .findAllAsync()
            .asFlowable()
            .filter(RealmResults::isLoaded);
    } else {
       return Flowable.just(realm
              .where(User.class)
              .findAll());
    }
}
```

Reading on background looper thread and passing unmanaged results on change using `copyFromRealm()` is slightly trickier, you should not use `copyFromRealm()` on a RealmResults on a UI thread.

Comment: Could I ask - why Flowable rather than Observable? Is this related to the expected size of RealmResults? And wherever this is used, it must always be followed by an unsubscribe, yes?

Comment: It was made to be Flowable because Flowable has a creation mode called LATEST for BackpressureStrategy so that it can't accidentally remember old states because RealmResults mutates in place so you'd just get the latest multiple times which might be unexpected, so they use LATEST BackpressureStrategy